# Natural progression in a curriculum for self-study of analysis

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, education, big-list

Would you list what is a natural and effective progression to self-study topics in analysis in order to gain a broad knowledge of the enormous corpus of knowledge that modern analysis involves. 
As a first step, I think that one should opt for Spivak and Apostol 1 and 2. But how would you organize a complete curriculum in analysis (every branch: e.g. real, complex, etc) up to modern research material? 
It would be really useful if you listed both topics and reference books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to consider the [Princeton Lectures in Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Lectures_in_Analysis), developed by Elias Stein.  The series covers Fourier, complex, real, and functional analysis, and stresses the interrelations between these fields.  Unlike some older texts, this series also includes extra material relevant to recent innovations in the field.

Comment: I also vouch for Stein's books. Note also that this should come after something like Spivak or Apostol or baby Rudin.

Comment: Could you specify what is the required background to read these $4$ books?

Comment: I've only read the complex analysis book in detail, and that required an undergraduate understanding of complex analysis and advanced calculus.

Comment: Yet another endorsement for Stein-Shakarchi books from me; they are a gem.  But *please* do not forget to name the second author.